# Can I use shared preferences for login/logout to store cookie for API headers

Tags: flutter, dart, cookies, token

Hi Im fairly new in Flutter, currently what I'm trying to do is create login page where user when logged in will get token. I need that token so I can use it for API calls in my app in the header section. Now I have seen that there is shared preferences which can help me that user stays logged in even after I exit the app. My question is after I log in with username and password in my body when I send API request how can I get the token from it and how can I store that token so I can use it for my future API calls. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Android and iOS both provide a secured local store. In Android it's encryptedSharedPreference and in iOS it's AES Encryption. That would be good place to store your cookie. There is a flutter library that switches between both depending on OS, https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

Here is also an article by logRocket that explaines the library in more detail https://blog.logrocket.com/securing-local-storage-flutter/